# How Would I refactor this Depth First Search function to remove mutation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

So I'm currently working my way through an algorithms course and this was provided as the answer for the leetcode problem "Palindrome Partitioning". I would like to be able to refactor the code so that it does not mutate the answer array and instead returns it. Preferably there would be no separate dfs function, just one recursive function called partition. I'm normally decent at this kind of thing but I'm struggling with this one:

```js
function partition(s) {
    const ans = [];
    const n = s.length;
    function dfs(start, part) {
        if (start == n) {
            ans.push([...part]);
            return;
        }
        for (let i = start + 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            const prefix = s.substring(start, i);
            if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                part.push(prefix);
                dfs(i, part);
                part.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    dfs(0, []);
    return ans;
}
```

This is my attempt so far:

```js
function partition(str, start) {
    const result = [];
    
    if (start == str.length) {
        result.push([str]);
    } else {
        for (let i = start + 1; i < str.length; i++) {
            const prefix = s.substring(start, i);

            if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                const results = partition(str, start + 1);
                
                if (results.length) {
                    for (const r of results) {
                        result.push([prefix, ...r]);
                    }
                } else {
                    result.push([prefix, s.substring(i + 1)]);
                }              
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to mutate the answer array? That's the thing about arrays: you can mutate them. And in your second example you are mutating `result`. Why `result` and not `ans`?

Comment: Your original code seems fine. I'm not sure what gains you expect by refactoring it. But the typical change to avoid mutations is `dfs(i, [...part, prefix]);` and remove the push/pop. This slows down your code with only a negligible gain in debuggability. The inner function is good because it avoids exposing default parameters that the caller could mess up.

Comment: Because it leads to better structured code to pass arguments into functions and have them mutate the values and return them than to have functions to mutate variables that live in different scopes. For example it would be better if partition was simply:
```js
function partition(str) {
return dfs(0, [], []);
}
```
but then there isn't a hell of a lot of point in having the partition function at all, it might as well just be replaced with
```js
dfs(str, start = [], partitions = []) {
...
}
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer inside your question -- I rolled back your edit. Instead you can post your answer in the answer section.

Comment: Was not aware this was a convention, will repost it in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt needs a few corrections:

- Spelling of `s` and `str` is not consistent
- The `start` parameter needs a default value of 0
- The recursive call is made with a wrong index. Not `start + 1`, but `i`
- The base case should not place the whole string in an array. On the contrary that newly pushed array should be empty: `result.push([])` or why not `return [[]]` immediately.
- `results.length` will never be zero when coming back from recursion; the `else` block will never execute -- it can be omitted.
- The `for` loop is making one iteration too few. The end condition should be `i <= s.length`

Here is the corrected version:

```
function partition(s, start=0) {
    if (start == s.length) {
        return [[]];
    }
    let result = [];
    for (let i = start + 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
        const prefix = s.slice(start, i);
        if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
            for (const part of partition(s, i)) {
                result.push([prefix, ...part]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this makes the solution a tad slower.

Comment: I don't understand why someone thought this answer is not useful.

Comment: I don't either. At the last place I worked, this was a 'holy war' issue which may explain it. Some are adamant that code should be written with early returns and chain functions and dislike the "Structured Coding" style and its indentation. I personally find this solution more maintainable and easy to think about. This style can trace its origins to Dijkstra's famous paper. Before then, GOTO was common and functions were multi entry, multi exit. He proposed we do away with that and make all functions single entry, single exit. Single entry became standard but sadly single exit did not.

Answer (score 1):

If you appreciate single-exit functions, you might also appreciate a (mutation-free) single-expression version:

```js
const isPalindrome = (s) => s .split ('') .reverse () .join ('') == s

const palindromePartition = (s, i = 1, p = s .slice (0, i)) => 
  s .length == 0
    ? [[]]
  : i > s .length
    ? []
  : [
      ... (isPalindrome (p) ? palindromePartition (s .slice (i)) .map (pp => [p, ...pp]) : []),
      ... (palindromePartition (s, i + 1))
    ]


console .log (palindromePartition ('aab'))
console .log (palindromePartition ('levelalevel'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here the body of our main function (so too the body of the `isPalindrome` helper) is a single expression.  Developed independently from the original or trincot's refactoring, it mostly still expresses the same logic, just structures it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here are Trincot's answers modified to be single entry, single exit. For anyone wondering why someone would want to do this, or for the inevitable downvoting it will get by the early return brigade, I've provided an analogy and a diagram at the bottom.

```js
function partition(str, start = 0) {
    const result = [];
    
    if (start != str.length) {
        for (let i = start + 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
            const prefix = str.slice(start, i);
            
            if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                const partitions = partition(str, i);
                
                if (partitions.length == 0) {
                    result.push([prefix]);
                } else {
                    for (const part of partitions) {
                        result.push([prefix, ...part]);
                    }
                }              
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

```js
function partition(str, start = 0) {
    const result = [];
    
    if (start != str.length) {
        for (let i = start + 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
            const prefix = str.slice(start, i);
            
            if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                const partitions = partition(str, i);
                
                for (const part of partitions) {
                    result.push([prefix, ...part]);
                }            
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result.length
        ? result
        : [[]];
}
```

```js
function partition(str, memo = {}) {
    const result = [];

    if (str) {
        if (memo[str]) {
            result.push(...memo[str])
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
                const prefix = str.slice(0, i);
                
                if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                    for (const part of partition(str.slice(i), memo)) {
                        result.push([prefix, ...part]);
                    }
                }
            }

            memo[str] = result;
        }
    }
    
    return result.length
        ? result
        : [[]];
}
```

```js
function partition(str, memo = {}) {
    const result = [];

    if (str) {
        if (memo[str]) {
            result.push(...memo[str]);
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
            
                const prefix = str.slice(0, i);
            
                if (isPalindrome(prefix)) {
                    const partitions = partition(str.slice(i), memo);

                    if (partitions.length == 0) {
                        result.push([prefix]);
                    } else {
                        for (const part of partitions) {
                            result.push([prefix, ...part]);
                        } 
                    }  
                }
            }

            memo[str] = result;
        }
    } else {
        result.push([]);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Structured Programming Hallway Analogy

Imagine you’re given a key and sent into a hallway. All along the hallway are locked doors to rooms and right at the end of the hallway is the exit.

As you come to a door along the hallway, you put your key in it and see if it opens. If it does, you enter the room. Inside the room there might be more doors. You try your key to see if any open. If they do, you walk inside and take a look around. Once you are finished in a room and there are no more doors to try you calmly walk back out to the hallway and out of the exit. This is structured programming.

Now imagine the same scenario. This time you come to a room in the hallway and the door unlocks. Great, you think, and walk straight in. Upon entering the room the door locks behind you, the floor caves in and you find yourself falling into darkness. You are being ejected from the building via a trap door. Congratulations, you have encountered an early return.

If you are working on a large codebase, the code you write will be worked on by people many years after you've departed the company. Which building would you rather explore? Which building do you want to leave for them?

Visually:
[image: Structured Programming Diagram]